# Многопользовательский чат C#

Tags: c#, чат

По уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=OdCPzknLX6Y написан чат, где есть сервер и клиент. При запуске сервера и клиента на локальной машине все замечательно работает, но если запустить сервер на одном пк, а клиента на другом одной локальной сети, то чат не работает. Как исправить данную проблему?

Клиент:

```
public partial class chatForm : Form
{
    private delegate void printer(string data);
    private delegate void cleaner();
    printer Printer;
    cleaner Cleaner;
    private Socket _serverSocket;
    private Thread _clientThread;
    private const string _serverHost = "192.168.1.35";
    private const int _serverPort = 9933;
    public chatForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Printer = new printer(print);
        Cleaner = new cleaner(clearChat);
        connect();
        _clientThread = new Thread(listner);
        _clientThread.IsBackground = true;
        _clientThread.Start();
    }
    private void listner()
    {
        while (_serverSocket.Connected)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
            int bytesRec = _serverSocket.Receive(buffer);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRec);
            if (data.Contains("#updatechat"))
            {
                UpdateChat(data);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    private void connect()
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(_serverHost);
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, _serverPort);
            _serverSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _serverSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        }
        catch { print("Сервер недоступен!"); }
    }
    private void clearChat()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(Cleaner);
            return;
        }
        chatBox.Clear();
    }
    private void UpdateChat(string data)
    {
        //#updatechat&userName~data|username~data
        clearChat();
        string[] messages = data.Split('&')[1].Split('|');
        int countMessages = messages.Length;
        if (countMessages <= 0) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < countMessages; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(messages[i])) continue;
                print(String.Format("[{0}]:{1}.", messages[i].Split('~')[0], messages[i].Split('~')[1]));
            }
            catch { continue; }
        }
    }
    private void send(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            int bytesSent = _serverSocket.Send(buffer);
        }
        catch { print("Связь с сервером прервалась...");}
    }
    private void print(string msg)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(Printer, msg);
            return;
        }
        if (chatBox.Text.Length == 0)
            chatBox.AppendText(msg);
        else
            chatBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + msg);
    }

    private void enterChat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = userName.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) return;
        send("#setname&" + Name);
        chatBox.Enabled = true;
        chat_msg.Enabled = true;
        chat_send.Enabled = true;
        userName.Enabled = false;
        enterChat.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void chat_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sendMessage();
    }
    private void sendMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            string data = chat_msg.Text;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) return;
            send("#newmsg&" + data);
            chat_msg.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при отправке сообщения!"); }
    }
    private void chatBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            sendMessage();
    }

    private void chat_msg_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            sendMessage();
    }
}
```

Сервер:

```
class Program
{
    private const string _serverHost = "192.168.1.35";
    private const int _serverPort = 9933;
    private static Thread _serverThread;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _serverThread = new Thread(startServer);
        _serverThread.IsBackground = true;
        _serverThread.Start();
        while (true)
            handlerCommands(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    private static void handlerCommands(string cmd)
    {
        cmd = cmd.ToLower();
        if (cmd.Contains("/getusers"))
        {
            int countUsers = Server.Clients.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < countUsers; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}]: {1}",i,Server.Clients[i].UserName);
            }
        }
    }
    private static void startServer()
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(_serverHost);
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, _serverPort);
        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
        socket.Listen(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Server has been started on IP: {0}.",ipEndPoint);
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket user = socket.Accept();
                Server.NewClient(user);
            }
            catch (Exception exp) { Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",exp.Message); }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что на сервере работает брандмауэр, который закрывает обращения по нестандартным портам для внешних подключений. В Windows 10 нажмите системную кнопку "Пуск" (стилизованное окно слева внизу экрана) и наберите "Брандмауэр и безопасность сети".  Там щёлкните "Дополнительные параметры" и добавьте разрешающее правило для входящих подключения на порту TCP 9933. Если дело в этом, то программа должна заработать.

Comment: А этот порт `9933` открыт наружу для работы на сервере? Проверьте настройки файервола на сервере, проверьте чтоб адрес на сервере соответствовал `192.168.1.35`, а то, может быть, у вас динамическая адресация и сервер поменял свой адрес после перезагрузки.

Comment: Вам нужно доработать программу сервера, чтоб программа определяла на старте ip-адрес машины, затем использовала его, вместо жестко прописанной константы,  и выводила бы вам на экран текущий прослушиваемый адрес и порт. А на клиенте нужно тоже избавиться от константы адреса и порта, а вводить их, а потом запускать соединение.

Comment: Брандмауэр полностью отключал. IP адрес статический.

Comment: @Bulson, а не лучше ли в этом случае `0.0.0.0` использовать?

Comment: добавил правила в брандмауэр, результат не изменился

Comment: какие-то ошибки?

Comment: Ошибка: "Сервер недоступен!" на другом ПК. Сервер 192.168.1.35 (брандмауэр выключен, ip статический), клиент 192.168.1.58 (брандмауэр выключен, ip статический). Пигуются оба компьютера без проблем.

Comment: Вот именно такая обработка ошибок `catch { print("Сервер недоступен!"); }`  всегда приводит к "непоняткам" и головной боли, хуже бывает только `catch {}`. Сделайте нормальную обработку ошибки, или поставьте точку останова на `catch(Exception ex)` и посмотрите `ex.Message`, что пишет?

Comment: Bulson, спасибо. Забыл про exception, сейчас посмотрю на что ругается)

Comment: Прописал exception, и теперь увидел ошибку: "Адрес несовместим с выбраным протоколом [fe80::f9b4:426b:d4a6:5c5c%11]:9933". Что она означает? Что неправильно прописано на клиенте? Почему на локальной машине ipv4, а на удаленной ipv6?

Comment: IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(_serverHost);
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0]; в этом коде почему то на удаленной машине получаю ipv6, а на локальной ipv4

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в сервере, а в межсетевом экране. Блокировать общение по локальной сети может так же и роутер, но в большинстве случаев это происходит из-за [Брандмауэра Windows](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%8D%D1%80_Windows) на стороне сервера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благо, его достаточно просто отключить как для определенного порта в настройках, так и глобально. Используя программу [Windows Updates Disabler](http://www.site2unblock.com/win-updates-disabler/) это можно сделать в два клика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это не помогает, универсальным способом будет применение [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) - утилиты для проброса вещания с специфичного порта через интернет. Ее так же применяют для расшаривания ресурсов при отсутствие статичного ip.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отключать полностью брандмауэр плохой совет. По хорошему лучше использовать непривилегированные порты, или открывать только определенные необходимые порты индивидуально. А не превращать свой комп в игрушку для троянов и прочей нечести.

Comment: @Bulson по хорошему лучше иметь зарплату 800 тысяч и пенсию в 25 лет, а на деле разработческая машина должна быть оснащена минимумом кастома вида антивирусов, увеличивающего временные издержки на разработку ПО. Настройкой фаервола должен заниматься администратор, а не программист.

Comment: Настройка собственного рабочего компа не бином Ньютона и каждый уважающий себя программер должен это делать самостоятельно. Или вы на дом приглашаете себе "мастеров" на час для установки и настройки винды или для установки Visual Studio?

Comment: @Bulson "трушный" программер, давай без обучений как жить? Что такого, что человек не знает как настроить пеку? Или он обязан с рождения все знания знать и уметь всё? Ну а че, он же МУЖЫК, обязан в тюрячке отсидеть срок и уметь унитаз починить. Ну и да, настройкой пк и прочего на работе делает девопс и сисадмин, а не программист. Если выработаете в ООО "Кабан и Ко" или ИП "Некидаев Х. У.", где вы "мастер на все руки", то это уже исключительно ваша беда и узколобое мировозрение о текущем айти

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен!
Спасибо Bulson, за то что натолкнул меня на Exception, что я действительно забыл прописать, чтобы увидеть ошибку!

Проблема была в нескольких сетевых адаптерах на ПК (сервер), ipHost.AddressList[0] на удаленном ПК был равен iPv6, а ipHost.AddressList[1] и был тот нужный локальный iPv4.